# chainsaws&blowers: Any guides/instructions on installing DIY air pre-filters on units with weak OEM filters?

Tags: small-engine, diy, two-stroke, modification

I really love the idea (in link below) of Echo's 'pre-filter' setup to ease/assist the actual/main air filter and would love to DIY something, am guessing a stiff-enough, heat tolerant mesh material would be fine for molding-in but I'd really love to find a guide or thread or video and googling for this has proved impossible so any advice or direction would be greatly appreciated!

Am hoping to install a pre-filter of sorts onto both my blowers & chainsaws at their next filter-changes although I'd be lying if I said I wasn't wanting a little peace-of-mind that the idea is sound, am picturing some sort of metal-mesh that's not restrictive and epoxied or physically-affixed into place, should be pretty simple and anything that'd delay filter cleanings would be a huge win for me!

Comment: Can you specify the models? I have 2 Echo blowers and 1 Echo chainsaw, and with 1 of the blowers a pre-filter would be totally useless. Plus it will be easier to assess with specific models.

Comment: Also, no link to the pre-filter you're talking about.